# How to query on divisibility in Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have this query in MySQL, which finds all rows where the ID minus 4 is divisible by 6.

```
SELECT * FROM stocks where ((id-4) % 6) = 0;
```

So, it returns rows 10, 16, 22, etc.

Now I am trying to do the same query in Eloquent, but I have a problem. If I do this, I get an error saying "a non-numeric value encountered":

```
$stocks = Stock::where((('id' - 4) % 6), 0)->get();
```

I understand that this is because `'id'` is not perceived to be a number here. However, if I try this, then the error is "use of unknown constant id":

```
$stocks = Stock::where(((id - 4) % 6), 0)->get();
```

So how can I perform this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution for this is using `raw expressions`.

Here is official doc [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions) for you.

So your query might look like

```
Stock::whereRaw('(id-4)%6=0')->get();
```

Comment: I am now getting `BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range` for some reason.

Comment: try  `Stock::whereRaw('(cast(id as SIGNED)-4)%6=0')->get();`

Comment: Check what query is being formed using `toSql()` method. This will help you in debugging.